# Return NaN output as a custom Text value

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a NaN output when selecting certain radio buttons on a form that I'm not sure how to workaround.

I have a list of 6 radio buttons for example, the 3 values are 'yes', 'no' & 'n/a'. I have a JavaScript function that calculates the values to provide an percentage score. So if 6 are ticked as 'yes' then it's 100% or if 5 are ticked 'yes' and one is 'n/a' then it's still 100%.

The issue occurs when all 6 are ticked as 'n/a' which is because the function is trying to divided by zero...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    var pass1 = $('.pass1:checked').length
    var fail1 = $('.fail1:checked').length
    var na1 = $('.na1:checked').length

    var pass1=Math.round(pass1/(6-na1)*100);

    $('.cat1_results').text(pass1)
    $('.no_results').text(fail1)

    $('#cat1score').val(pass1);
})
});
```

I have a BODMAS rule that calculates the score but if there are Zero ticked as pass and 6 are n/a then it's trying to divide zero by zero. Is there a way I can use that if a user selects all 'n/a' then it will just return 'na'?

Comment: isNaN(value) is a function you can use to check NaN

Comment: why not do a simple `if (na1 !== 6)` before your ui updating

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make your code typesafe using `parseInt`, handle that condition when `na1` will be `6` separately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var pass1 = parseInt($('.pass1:checked').length);
        var fail1 = parseInt($('.fail1:checked').length);
        var na1 = parseInt($('.na1:checked').length);

        var pass1 = 0;
        if(na1 == 6){
            pass1 = 100;
        }
        else{
            pass1=Math.round(pass1/(6-na1)*100);
        }

        $('.cat1_results').text(pass1)
        $('.no_results').text(fail1)

        $('#cat1score').val(pass1);
    })
});
```

Comment: and how would that help in this particular example? the issue is that na1===6 will cause division by 0, parseInt of 6 is still a 6

Comment: I misunderstood it, I have updated my answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

isNaN(value) is a function you can use to check NaN

```
var pass1=Math.round(pass1/(6-na1)*100);
    if(isNaN(pass1){
      //NaN
      //... do things
    }else{
      $('.cat1_results').text(pass1)
      $('.no_results').text(fail1)

      $('#cat1score').val(pass1);
    }
```